# Panorama with multiple background images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Using windows phone 8.

What would be my best approach in getting multiple background layers in a panorama to create a parallax effect while scrolling?

Any chance of avoiding writing the entire control from scratch?

Comment: have you tried adding Panaroma control inside a Panorama control's PanoramaItem

Comment: Also the parent Panorama's background should have wider dimensions than the Panorama inside the PanoramaItem. This will give a better parallax effect

Comment: I don't think that will work, the images will be way too far down and I think it breaks the UX guidelines about interaction with controls.

Comment: I was wrong with the panorama inside panorama. You can have a Panorama inside a grid. grid will be the parent and its background will be static. The panorama inside grid can have a background that will then produce a Parallax effect, not perfect but thats the best you can do

Comment: Great idea, that's two layers if it works, I wonder what the drawback would be to writing one from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a Panorama inside a grid. grid will be the parent and its background will be static. The panorama inside grid can have a background that will then produce a Parallax effect, not perfect but thats the best you can do.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Background.png" />
        </Grid.Background>
    <phone:Panorama>
        <phone:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Background-upper-layer.jpg">
                </ImageBrush>
            </phone:Panorama.Background>

        <!--your code-->

    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```